# How to send cookies saved in browser from Angular js to servlet using angular js POST method?

Tags: angularjs, servlet-filters

here is my `AngularJs` code

```
<script>


    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('employeeController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.myFunction = function() {
            // $scope.employees = response.userList;  
            var app = 'AirFare';
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date();
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "loaduser",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                data: {application: app, from: d1, to: d2}
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.firstName = response.estate;
                $scope.employees = response.estate;  
                //console.log($scope.employees+" :::  "+JSON.stringify($scope.employees));
            });
        }

    }
    )
    .config(function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    })
    ;
```

In the above code I have tried to get request in filter but I'm unable to get cookie saved in browser from that request

Comment: Cookies should be automatically added to request as long as the `path` matches. I would recommend you to check if there is any problem with the `path` of cookies.

Comment: correct but i have only one jsp page. in that page i have used the above script, for testing purpose at first request i have created the cookie and added in the response. in that response page i have a button, while clicking that i cant get cookie in servlet filter,

Comment: i have created and added cookie by using OWASP-ESAPI jar

Answer (score 0):

In your server side response header should contain below settings:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-client-side-url
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: Thanks! but still its not working for me. this is i have added in my filter

Comment: ESAPI.httpUtilities().getCurrentResponse().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080/*");
     ESAPI.httpUtilities().getCurrentResponse().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");